# What is the best way to dynamically assign class on html in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using a bootstrap template in a codeigniter application. Here, I have a  menu which is in a different file. I call the same file (i.e. menu) on all of the pages. And, if I put `class="active"` in a menu item, it gets highlighted so that the user can know where in the menu s/he is. So, my question is how do I set the `class` to the menu item dynamically ?

One common method is, I could just pass a variable which stores the name of the menu item and simply put check like this `<li <?php if($var=='menuItem'){echo ' class="active"';} ?>></li>`
But I'm still searching if there is any method more dynamic than this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is how I would do it.  Though you can simplify your code `<li <?php $var=='menuItem' && echo 'class="active"'; ?>></li>`

Comment: Actually the echo wont work that way sorry. You could use print instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really enough information about exactly how your menu works, or your site structure, but I often analyze the URL segments to decide if a menu item is active or not. For instance:

Suppose your URL is this:

```
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/index.php/news/page_1
```

And your main menu is something like:

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
```

I would add class="active" by checking the URL segments like this:

```
<?php echo ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'news') ? 'active':''; ?>
```

To get

```
<li><a href="#" class="<?php echo ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'home') ? 'active':''; ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="<?php echo ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'news') ? 'active':''; ?>">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="<?php echo ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'about') ? 'active':''; ?>">About</a></li>
```

You can also look at segment 2 etc for sub menu's. The home page might be blank which you can handle by adding a check for segment 1 being null.

Alternatively you can set the first segment in a variable and that can be a bit cleaner too.

```
<?php $page = $this->uri->segment(1); ?>
<li><a href="#" class="<?php echo ($page == 'home') ? 'active':''; ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="<?php echo ($page == 'news') ? 'active':''; ?>">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="<?php echo ($page == 'about') ? 'active':''; ?>">About</a></li>
```

You can read about URL segments here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Hope that helps,

Comment: This more simple and efficient than the one I mentioned.Thank you for the idea.